# Pyinstaller output .exe closes immediately

Tags: python, pyinstaller, python-exec

I am trying to turn a python file into an executable with Pyinstaller.
The file calls onto different modules as well as different libraries.
When executing the command `pyinstaller --onefile instabot.py` a instabot.exe file is produced and placed into the dict folder as expected.
**When I try to run such file though, it opens the terminal for a second, and then it closes it immediately.**
I tried leaving the .exe file in the dict folder, as well as moving it in the top-level folder, but none worked. Even when placing the .exe file at the same level as the original instabot.py file (so with access to all the used modules and libraries), it still acts the same...
I also trying removing the --onefile option, but the result is the same.

I am running the command on a Windows 10 machine. Pyinstaller is at its latest version (I used `pip install -U pyinstaller` )

Unfortunately I do not have any more input as to why this issue may be arising...

To replicate the issue I am facing, you can close the git repository linked here: https://github.com/davidwickerhf/desktop-instabot
then, in a virtual environment, install the modules in the requirements.txt file ( `pip install -r requirements` )

Any help, suggestion or question would be much appreciated.

If any further information is needed, I'd be more than happy to provide it - I just am not sure at the current moment what more useful information I can provide.

**EDIT 2**
When I run the command `pyinstaller --windowed --onefile --debug=all instabot.py`, when opening the .exe file I receive the error message= **'Failed to execute script pyiboot01_bootstrap'**

**EDIT 1**
I ran the command `pyinstaller instabot.py --debug=imports` and when executing the output .exe (inside the dist folder, from the terminal), I receive the following messages:

```
import _frozen_importlib # frozen
import _imp # builtin
import '_thread' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import '_warnings' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import '_weakref' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import '_frozen_importlib_external' # <class '_frozen_importlib.FrozenImporter'>
import 'nt' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import '_io' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import 'marshal' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import 'winreg' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
# installing zipimport hook
import 'time' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import 'zipimport' # <class '_frozen_importlib.FrozenImporter'>
# installed zipimport hook
# zipimport: found 147 names in 'D:\\dhfwi\\Projects\\wickerdevs\\instabot\\desktop-instabot\\dist\\instabot\\base_library.zip'
import '_codecs' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import codecs # loaded from Zip D:\dhfwi\Projects\wickerdevs\instabot\desktop-instabot\dist\instabot\base_library.zip\codecs.pyc
import encodings.aliases # loaded from Zip D:\dhfwi\Projects\wickerdevs\instabot\desktop-instabot\dist\instabot\base_library.zip\encodings\aliases.pyc
import encodings # loaded from Zip D:\dhfwi\Projects\wickerdevs\instabot\desktop-instabot\dist\instabot\base_library.zip\encodings\__init__.pyc
import encodings.utf_8 # loaded from Zip D:\dhfwi\Projects\wickerdevs\instabot\desktop-instabot\dist\instabot\base_library.zip\encodings\utf_8.pyc
import encodings.cp1252 # loaded from Zip D:\dhfwi\Projects\wickerdevs\instabot\desktop-instabot\dist\instabot\base_library.zip\encodings\cp1252.pyc
import '_signal' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import encodings.latin_1 # loaded from Zip D:\dhfwi\Projects\wickerdevs\instabot\desktop-instabot\dist\instabot\base_library.zip\encodings\latin_1.pyc
import '_abc' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import abc # loaded from Zip D:\dhfwi\Projects\wickerdevs\instabot\desktop-instabot\dist\instabot\base_library.zip\abc.pyc
import io # loaded from Zip D:\dhfwi\Projects\wickerdevs\instabot\desktop-instabot\dist\instabot\base_library.zip\io.pyc
import '_struct' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import 'zlib' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
# PyInstaller: FrozenImporter(D:\dhfwi\Projects\wickerdevs\instabot\desktop-instabot\dist\instabot\instabot.exe?288734)
import os # PyInstaller PYZ
import stat # PyInstaller PYZ
import '_stat' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import 'stat' # <pyimod03_importers.FrozenImporter object at 0x00000230F3104190>
# _collections_abc not found in PYZ
import _collections_abc # loaded from Zip D:\dhfwi\Projects\wickerdevs\instabot\desktop-instabot\dist\instabot\base_library.zip\_collections_abc.pyc
import ntpath # PyInstaller PYZ
import genericpath # PyInstaller PYZ
import 'genericpath' # <pyimod03_importers.FrozenImporter object at 0x00000230F3104190>
import 'ntpath' # <pyimod03_importers.FrozenImporter object at 0x00000230F3104190>
import 'os' # <pyimod03_importers.FrozenImporter object at 0x00000230F3104190>
import ctypes # PyInstaller PYZ
# types not found in PYZ
import types # loaded from Zip D:\dhfwi\Projects\wickerdevs\instabot\desktop-instabot\dist\instabot\base_library.zip\types.pyc
# _ctypes not found in PYZ
# extension module '_ctypes' loaded from 'D:\\dhfwi\\Projects\\wickerdevs\\instabot\\desktop-instabot\\dist\\instabot\\_ctypes.pyd'
# extension module '_ctypes' executed from 'D:\\dhfwi\\Projects\\wickerdevs\\instabot\\desktop-instabot\\dist\\instabot\\_ctypes.pyd'
import '_ctypes' # <_frozen_importlib_external.ExtensionFileLoader object at 0x00000230F317DB50>
import ctypes._endian # PyInstaller PYZ
import 'ctypes._endian' # <pyimod03_importers.FrozenImporter object at 0x00000230F3104190>
import 'ctypes' # <pyimod03_importers.FrozenImporter object at 0x00000230F3104190>
# re not found in PYZ
# enum not found in PYZ
import enum # loaded from Zip D:\dhfwi\Projects\wickerdevs\instabot\desktop-instabot\dist\instabot\base_library.zip\enum.pyc
# sre_compile not found in PYZ
import '_sre' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
# sre_parse not found in PYZ
# sre_constants not found in PYZ
import sre_constants # loaded from Zip D:\dhfwi\Projects\wickerdevs\instabot\desktop-instabot\dist\instabot\base_library.zip\sre_constants.pyc
import sre_parse # loaded from Zip D:\dhfwi\Projects\wickerdevs\instabot\desktop-instabot\dist\instabot\base_library.zip\sre_parse.pyc
import sre_compile # loaded from Zip D:\dhfwi\Projects\wickerdevs\instabot\desktop-instabot\dist\instabot\base_library.zip\sre_compile.pyc
# functools not found in PYZ
# collections not found in PYZ
# heapq not found in PYZ
import '_heapq' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import heapq # loaded from Zip D:\dhfwi\Projects\wickerdevs\instabot\desktop-instabot\dist\instabot\base_library.zip\heapq.pyc
import 'itertools' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
# keyword not found in PYZ
import keyword # loaded from Zip D:\dhfwi\Projects\wickerdevs\instabot\desktop-instabot\dist\instabot\base_library.zip\keyword.pyc
# operator not found in PYZ
import '_operator' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import operator # loaded from Zip D:\dhfwi\Projects\wickerdevs\instabot\desktop-instabot\dist\instabot\base_library.zip\operator.pyc
# reprlib not found in PYZ
import reprlib # loaded from Zip D:\dhfwi\Projects\wickerdevs\instabot\desktop-instabot\dist\instabot\base_library.zip\reprlib.pyc
import '_collections' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import collections # loaded from Zip D:\dhfwi\Projects\wickerdevs\instabot\desktop-instabot\dist\instabot\base_library.zip\collections\__init__.pyc
import '_functools' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import functools # loaded from Zip D:\dhfwi\Projects\wickerdevs\instabot\desktop-instabot\dist\instabot\base_library.zip\functools.pyc
import '_locale' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
# copyreg not found in PYZ
import copyreg # loaded from Zip D:\dhfwi\Projects\wickerdevs\instabot\desktop-instabot\dist\instabot\base_library.zip\copyreg.pyc
import re # loaded from Zip D:\dhfwi\Projects\wickerdevs\instabot\desktop-instabot\dist\instabot\base_library.zip\re.pyc
import multiprocessing # PyInstaller PYZ
import multiprocessing.context # PyInstaller PYZ
import threading # PyInstaller PYZ
# _weakrefset not found in PYZ
import _weakrefset # loaded from Zip D:\dhfwi\Projects\wickerdevs\instabot\desktop-instabot\dist\instabot\base_library.zip\_weakrefset.pyc
import 'threading' # <pyimod03_importers.FrozenImporter object at 0x00000230F3104190>
import multiprocessing.process # PyInstaller PYZ
import signal # PyInstaller PYZ
import 'signal' # <pyimod03_importers.FrozenImporter object at 0x00000230F3104190>
import 'multiprocessing.process' # <pyimod03_importers.FrozenImporter object at 0x00000230F3104190>
import multiprocessing.reduction # PyInstaller PYZ
import pickle # PyInstaller PYZ
import _compat_pickle # PyInstaller PYZ
import '_compat_pickle' # <pyimod03_importers.FrozenImporter object at 0x00000230F3104190>
import '_pickle' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
# org not found in PYZ
import 'pickle' # <pyimod03_importers.FrozenImporter object at 0x00000230F3104190>
import socket # PyInstaller PYZ
# _socket not found in PYZ
# extension module '_socket' loaded from 'D:\\dhfwi\\Projects\\wickerdevs\\instabot\\desktop-instabot\\dist\\instabot\\_socket.pyd'
# extension module '_socket' executed from 'D:\\dhfwi\\Projects\\wickerdevs\\instabot\\desktop-instabot\\dist\\instabot\\_socket.pyd'
import '_socket' # <_frozen_importlib_external.ExtensionFileLoader object at 0x00000230F4C46760>
import selectors # PyInstaller PYZ
# collections.abc not found in PYZ
import collections.abc # loaded from Zip D:\dhfwi\Projects\wickerdevs\instabot\desktop-instabot\dist\instabot\base_library.zip\collections\abc.pyc
import 'math' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
# select not found in PYZ
# extension module 'select' loaded from 'D:\\dhfwi\\Projects\\wickerdevs\\instabot\\desktop-instabot\\dist\\instabot\\select.pyd'
# extension module 'select' executed from 'D:\\dhfwi\\Projects\\wickerdevs\\instabot\\desktop-instabot\\dist\\instabot\\select.pyd'
import 'select' # <_frozen_importlib_external.ExtensionFileLoader object at 0x00000230F4C54DF0>
import 'selectors' # <pyimod03_importers.FrozenImporter object at 0x00000230F3104190>
import 'errno' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import 'socket' # <pyimod03_importers.FrozenImporter object at 0x00000230F3104190>
import '_winapi' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import 'multiprocessing.reduction' # <pyimod03_importers.FrozenImporter object at 0x00000230F3104190>
import 'multiprocessing.context' # <pyimod03_importers.FrozenImporter object at 0x00000230F3104190>
import 'multiprocessing' # <pyimod03_importers.FrozenImporter object at 0x00000230F3104190>
import multiprocessing.spawn # PyInstaller PYZ
import runpy # PyInstaller PYZ
import importlib # PyInstaller PYZ
# warnings not found in PYZ
import warnings # loaded from Zip D:\dhfwi\Projects\wickerdevs\instabot\desktop-instabot\dist\instabot\base_library.zip\warnings.pyc
import 'importlib' # <pyimod03_importers.FrozenImporter object at 0x00000230F3104190>
import importlib.machinery # PyInstaller PYZ
import 'importlib.machinery' # <pyimod03_importers.FrozenImporter object at 0x00000230F3104190>
import importlib.util # PyInstaller PYZ
import importlib.abc # PyInstaller PYZ
import typing # PyInstaller PYZ
import contextlib # PyInstaller PYZ
import 'contextlib' # <pyimod03_importers.FrozenImporter object at 0x00000230F3104190>
import 'typing' # <pyimod03_importers.FrozenImporter object at 0x00000230F3104190>
import 'importlib.abc' # <pyimod03_importers.FrozenImporter object at 0x00000230F3104190>
import 'importlib.util' # <pyimod03_importers.FrozenImporter object at 0x00000230F3104190>
import pkgutil # PyInstaller PYZ
# weakref not found in PYZ
import weakref # loaded from Zip D:\dhfwi\Projects\wickerdevs\instabot\desktop-instabot\dist\instabot\base_library.zip\weakref.pyc
import 'pkgutil' # <pyimod03_importers.FrozenImporter object at 0x00000230F3104190>
import 'runpy' # <pyimod03_importers.FrozenImporter object at 0x00000230F3104190>
import multiprocessing.util # PyInstaller PYZ
import 'atexit' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import subprocess # PyInstaller PYZ
# pwd not found in PYZ
# grp not found in PYZ
import 'msvcrt' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import 'subprocess' # <pyimod03_importers.FrozenImporter object at 0x00000230F3104190>
import 'multiprocessing.util' # <pyimod03_importers.FrozenImporter object at 0x00000230F3104190>
import 'multiprocessing.spawn' # <pyimod03_importers.FrozenImporter object at 0x00000230F3104190>
import multiprocessing.popen_spawn_win32 # PyInstaller PYZ
import 'multiprocessing.popen_spawn_win32' # <pyimod03_importers.FrozenImporter object at 0x00000230F3104190>
import ssl # PyInstaller PYZ
# _ssl not found in PYZ
# extension module '_ssl' loaded from 'D:\\dhfwi\\Projects\\wickerdevs\\instabot\\desktop-instabot\\dist\\instabot\\_ssl.pyd'
# extension module '_ssl' executed from 'D:\\dhfwi\\Projects\\wickerdevs\\instabot\\desktop-instabot\\dist\\instabot\\_ssl.pyd'
import '_ssl' # <_frozen_importlib_external.ExtensionFileLoader object at 0x00000230F4F526A0>
import base64 # PyInstaller PYZ
import 'binascii' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import 'base64' # <pyimod03_importers.FrozenImporter object at 0x00000230F3104190>
import 'ssl' # <pyimod03_importers.FrozenImporter object at 0x00000230F3104190>
import logging # PyInstaller PYZ
# traceback not found in PYZ
# linecache not found in PYZ
import tokenize # PyInstaller PYZ
import token # PyInstaller PYZ
import 'token' # <pyimod03_importers.FrozenImporter object at 0x00000230F3104190>
import 'tokenize' # <pyimod03_importers.FrozenImporter object at 0x00000230F3104190>
import linecache # loaded from Zip D:\dhfwi\Projects\wickerdevs\instabot\desktop-instabot\dist\instabot\base_library.zip\linecache.pyc
import traceback # loaded from Zip D:\dhfwi\Projects\wickerdevs\instabot\desktop-instabot\dist\instabot\base_library.zip\traceback.pyc
import string # PyInstaller PYZ
import '_string' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import 'string' # <pyimod03_importers.FrozenImporter object at 0x00000230F3104190>
import 'logging' # <pyimod03_importers.FrozenImporter object at 0x00000230F3104190>
# clear builtins._
# clear sys.path
# clear sys.argv
# clear sys.ps1
# clear sys.ps2
# clear sys.last_type
# clear sys.last_value
# clear sys.last_traceback
# clear sys.path_hooks
# clear sys.path_importer_cache
# clear sys.meta_path
# clear sys.__interactivehook__
# restore sys.stdin
# restore sys.stdout
# restore sys.stderr
# cleanup[2] removing sys
# cleanup[2] removing builtins
# cleanup[2] removing _frozen_importlib
# cleanup[2] removing _imp
# cleanup[2] removing _thread
# cleanup[2] removing _warnings
# cleanup[2] removing _weakref
# cleanup[2] removing _frozen_importlib_external
# cleanup[2] removing nt
# cleanup[2] removing _io
# cleanup[2] removing marshal
# cleanup[2] removing winreg
# cleanup[2] removing time
# cleanup[2] removing zipimport
# cleanup[2] removing _codecs
# cleanup[2] removing codecs
# cleanup[2] removing encodings.aliases
# cleanup[2] removing encodings
# cleanup[2] removing encodings.utf_8
# cleanup[2] removing encodings.cp1252
# cleanup[2] removing _signal
# cleanup[2] removing encodings.latin_1
# cleanup[2] removing _abc
# cleanup[2] removing abc
# cleanup[2] removing io
# cleanup[2] removing __main__
# cleanup[2] removing struct
# cleanup[2] removing _struct
# cleanup[2] removing pyimod01_os_path
# cleanup[2] removing pyimod02_archive
# cleanup[2] removing zlib
# cleanup[2] removing pyimod03_importers
# cleanup[2] removing _stat
# cleanup[2] removing stat
# cleanup[2] removing _collections_abc
# cleanup[2] removing genericpath
# cleanup[2] removing ntpath
# cleanup[2] removing os.path
# cleanup[2] removing os
# cleanup[2] removing types
# cleanup[2] removing _ctypes
# cleanup[2] removing ctypes._endian
# cleanup[2] removing ctypes
# cleanup[2] removing enum
# cleanup[2] removing _sre
# cleanup[2] removing sre_constants
# destroy sre_constants
# cleanup[2] removing sre_parse
# cleanup[2] removing sre_compile
# cleanup[2] removing _heapq
# cleanup[2] removing heapq
# cleanup[2] removing itertools
# cleanup[2] removing keyword
# destroy keyword
# cleanup[2] removing _operator
# cleanup[2] removing operator
# cleanup[2] removing reprlib
# destroy reprlib
# cleanup[2] removing _collections
# cleanup[2] removing collections
# cleanup[2] removing _functools
# cleanup[2] removing functools
# cleanup[2] removing _locale
# cleanup[2] removing copyreg
# cleanup[2] removing re
# cleanup[2] removing _weakrefset
# destroy _weakrefset
# cleanup[2] removing threading
# cleanup[2] removing signal
# cleanup[2] removing multiprocessing.process
# cleanup[2] removing _compat_pickle
# cleanup[2] removing _pickle
# cleanup[2] removing pickle
# cleanup[2] removing _socket
# cleanup[2] removing collections.abc
# cleanup[2] removing math
# cleanup[2] removing select
# cleanup[2] removing selectors
# cleanup[2] removing errno
# cleanup[2] removing socket
# cleanup[2] removing _winapi
# cleanup[2] removing multiprocessing.reduction
# cleanup[2] removing multiprocessing.context
# cleanup[2] removing __mp_main__
# destroy __main__
# cleanup[2] removing multiprocessing
# cleanup[2] removing importlib._bootstrap
# cleanup[2] removing importlib._bootstrap_external
# cleanup[2] removing warnings
# cleanup[2] removing importlib
# cleanup[2] removing importlib.machinery
# cleanup[2] removing contextlib
# cleanup[2] removing typing
# destroy typing
# cleanup[2] removing importlib.abc
# cleanup[2] removing importlib.util
# cleanup[2] removing weakref
# cleanup[2] removing pkgutil
# destroy pkgutil
# cleanup[2] removing runpy
# cleanup[2] removing atexit
# cleanup[2] removing msvcrt
# cleanup[2] removing subprocess
# destroy subprocess
# cleanup[2] removing multiprocessing.util
# cleanup[2] removing multiprocessing.spawn
# cleanup[2] removing multiprocessing.popen_spawn_win32
# cleanup[2] removing _ssl
# cleanup[2] removing binascii
# cleanup[2] removing base64
# cleanup[2] removing ssl
# cleanup[2] removing token
# destroy token
# cleanup[2] removing tokenize
# cleanup[2] removing linecache
# cleanup[2] removing traceback
# cleanup[2] removing _string
# cleanup[2] removing string
# destroy string
# cleanup[2] removing logging
# cleanup[3] wiping logging
# destroy traceback
# cleanup[3] wiping _string
# cleanup[3] wiping linecache
# destroy tokenize
# cleanup[3] wiping ssl
# destroy base64
# cleanup[3] wiping binascii
# cleanup[3] wiping _ssl
# cleanup[3] wiping multiprocessing.popen_spawn_win32
# cleanup[3] wiping multiprocessing.spawn
# destroy runpy
# cleanup[3] wiping multiprocessing.util
# destroy weakref
# cleanup[3] wiping msvcrt
# cleanup[3] wiping atexit
# destroy atexit
# cleanup[3] wiping importlib.util
# cleanup[3] wiping importlib.abc
# cleanup[3] wiping contextlib
# cleanup[3] wiping importlib.machinery
# cleanup[3] wiping importlib
# destroy importlib.machinery
# destroy importlib.abc
# destroy importlib.util
# cleanup[3] wiping warnings
# cleanup[3] wiping importlib._bootstrap_external
# cleanup[3] wiping importlib._bootstrap
# cleanup[3] wiping multiprocessing
# destroy multiprocessing.util
# cleanup[3] wiping multiprocessing.context
# destroy multiprocessing.process
# destroy multiprocessing.reduction
# cleanup[3] wiping _winapi
# cleanup[3] wiping socket
# destroy selectors
# cleanup[3] wiping errno
# cleanup[3] wiping select
# cleanup[3] wiping math
# cleanup[3] wiping collections.abc
# cleanup[3] wiping _socket
# cleanup[3] wiping pickle
# destroy _compat_pickle
# cleanup[3] wiping _pickle
# cleanup[3] wiping signal
# cleanup[3] wiping threading
# cleanup[3] wiping re
# destroy enum
# destroy sre_compile
# cleanup[3] wiping copyreg
# cleanup[3] wiping _locale
# destroy _locale
# cleanup[3] wiping functools
# cleanup[3] wiping _functools
# destroy _functools
# cleanup[3] wiping collections
# destroy heapq
# destroy collections.abc
# cleanup[3] wiping _collections
# destroy _collections
# cleanup[3] wiping operator
# cleanup[3] wiping _operator
# destroy _operator
# cleanup[3] wiping itertools
# cleanup[3] wiping _heapq
# cleanup[3] wiping sre_parse
# cleanup[3] wiping _sre
# cleanup[3] wiping ctypes
# destroy ctypes._endian
# cleanup[3] wiping _ctypes
# cleanup[3] wiping types
# cleanup[3] wiping os
# destroy ntpath
# cleanup[3] wiping genericpath
# cleanup[3] wiping _collections_abc
# cleanup[3] wiping stat
# cleanup[3] wiping _stat
# destroy _stat
# cleanup[3] wiping pyimod03_importers
# cleanup[3] wiping zlib
# cleanup[3] wiping pyimod02_archive
# cleanup[3] wiping pyimod01_os_path
# cleanup[3] wiping _struct
# cleanup[3] wiping struct
# cleanup[3] wiping io
# destroy abc
# cleanup[3] wiping _abc
# cleanup[3] wiping encodings.latin_1
# cleanup[3] wiping _signal
# cleanup[3] wiping encodings.cp1252
# cleanup[3] wiping encodings.utf_8
# cleanup[3] wiping encodings
# destroy codecs
# destroy encodings.aliases
# destroy encodings.utf_8
# destroy encodings.cp1252
# destroy encodings.latin_1
# cleanup[3] wiping _codecs
# cleanup[3] wiping zipimport
# destroy _frozen_importlib_external
# cleanup[3] wiping time
# cleanup[3] wiping winreg
# cleanup[3] wiping marshal
# cleanup[3] wiping _io
# cleanup[3] wiping nt
# cleanup[3] wiping _weakref
# cleanup[3] wiping _warnings
# cleanup[3] wiping _thread
# cleanup[3] wiping _imp
# destroy _imp
# cleanup[3] wiping _frozen_importlib
# cleanup[3] wiping sys
# cleanup[3] wiping builtins
# destroy _ssl
# destroy _socket
# destroy zlib
# destroy _struct
# destroy _signal
# destroy winreg
# destroy stat
# destroy genericpath
# destroy encodings
# destroy ctypes
# destroy multiprocessing
# destroy multiprocessing.spawn
# destroy multiprocessing.popen_spawn_win32
# destroy ssl
# destroy logging
# destroy _sre
# destroy sre_parse
# destroy _abc
# destroy errno
# destroy msvcrt
# destroy _thread
# destroy _warnings
# destroy time
# destroy signal
# destroy threading
# destroy copyreg
# destroy pickle
# destroy socket
# destroy multiprocessing.context
# destroy _winapi
# destroy io
# destroy binascii
# destroy linecache
# destroy _weakref
# destroy _collections_abc
# destroy _heapq
# destroy _pickle
# destroy nt
# destroy importlib
# destroy os
# destroy warnings
# destroy zipimport
# destroy math
# destroy select
# destroy _string
# destroy io
# destroy itertools
# destroy collections
# destroy contextlib
# destroy functools
# destroy operator
# destroy re
# destroy types
# destroy _frozen_importlib
# clear sys.audit hooks
```

Comment: It sounds like your program has a hidden import. Have you gone through  the troubleshooting steps under *When things go wrong* in the `pyinstaller` documentation?

Comment: @BoarGules Thenk you for your kind response. I'll check what I can do about eventual hidden imports and get back to you

Comment: @BoarGules I went through the documentation you mentioned, though I am not sure how to list hidden imports, nor if that's what's causing the issue (as I am not receiving any import error) 

When I execute the file from terminal, I receive no output

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a solution to this.
The command that worked for me to compile my python windowed Tkinter app was this:

For production:

```
pyinstaller run.py --onefile --windowed --noconsole --icon "instabot-config\instaclient.ico" --name instabot --add-data "instabot-config\instaclient.ico;." --add-data "instabot-config\botstate.json;." --add-data "instabot-config\instabot.log;." --clean
```

I believe I just needed to make sure to add the correct files.

For testing (this might be more helpful to everyone who wants to see why the executable isn't startint or running properly):

```
pyinstaller run.py --onefile --debug=all --add-data "\instabot-config\instaclient.ico;." --add-data "instabot-config\botstate.json;." --add-data "instabot-config\instabot.log;." --clean
```